# datetime.time object returns an error when trying to work with it?

Tags: python, datetime

I am given an output like this:

```
[('John', datetime.time(4, 35)), ('Emy', datetime.time(19, 0))]
```

Given this output I want to be able to work with the first element of each tuple (the datetime.time objects).

For example I can't do:

```
(datetime.combine(date(1,1,1), datetime.time(4, 35)) + timedelta(hours = 4)).time()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e2c5fbe62c16> in <module>
----> 1 (datetime.combine(date(1,1,1), datetime.time(4, 35)) + timedelta(hours = tz)).time()

TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Please advise how to solve the issue.

Comment: This just sound like you've done `from datetime import datetime`, so `datetime.time` in your code refers to the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) method of the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) class, when what you want is the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects) class of the [`datetime` *module*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: @deceze why did you close the question? Please guide me how to solve it. I am sorry I didn't understand what should I do?
from datetime import time?

Comment: Yes, `from datetime import time`, then use just `time(4, 35)`.

Comment: Yes - you're mixing the `datetime` class methods like `datetime.combine` with `datetime` module calls like `datetime.time`. You'll have an easier time working with it if you just `import datetime` and name the `datetime` class when you mean the class - `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(...), datetime.time(...))` etc. You can also use `from datetime import time` but as you've seen that can be harder to follow.

Comment: @deceze I am getting this object from postgres table. This is a result of a query.

Comment: But really, since you want to be working with values from your tuples, this is all a non-issue if you do e.g. `l[0][1]` to get the existing `time` object from your list.

Comment: @deceze I am trying to import just datetime: `import datetime`
But still can't run:
`(datetime.datetime.combine(date(1,1,1), l[0][1]) + datetime.timedelta(hours = tz)).time()`

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper see my last comment, still does't work

Comment: Works for me if I name the `datetime.date` constructor. I don't have your tuple list handy but manually instantiating the `datetime.time()` value works - `(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1), datetime.time(4, 35)) + datetime.timedelta(hours=4)).time()`. That said, if you're always just adding a known number of hours what about just using the `replace` method on `datetime.time` rather than converting to a datetime and then converting back to a time?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I am adding a timezone of the user. It's always different

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper you are using `import datetime`?

Comment: Yes, that's all with `import datetime`. My alternate suggestion is `user_time = l[0][1] # or whatever` then `user_time = user_time.replace(hour=user_time.hour + tz)` - although if you're trying to convert from UTC to a user's time or vice versa both approaches fail to cover a whole lot of special cases.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I am using `l[0][1]` instead of `datetime.time(4, 35))` doesn't work.
Really confusing...

Comment: Then your `l[0][1]` probably isn't a `datetime.time` instance.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper here is the proof that it is: `<class 'datetime.time'>`

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `print(type(l[0][1]))`

Comment: Works for me: `>>> l = [('foo', datetime.time(4, 30))]
>>> (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1), l[0][1]) + datetime.timedelta(hours=4)).time()
datetime.time(8, 30)`

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `print(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1), l[0][1]))`
Returns `0001-01-01 04:35:00`

Comment: The `datetime.time` in your very first snippet in your question refers to the `time` class of the `datetime` module. It’s the “absolute” name of that class. What the other names refer to in the code that you wrote depends on what `import` statements you used. The confusing part is that the module is named `datetime` and in it are classes `datetime`, `date` and `time`, and `datetime` objects also have `date` and `time` methods. So, give us a full example in your question where that’s all clearly disambiguated with your `import` statements.

Comment: @deceze I am using `import datetime`.

Comment: @deceze please reopen the question

Comment: Update your question to show a clear, self-contained example of that. Don’t clarify it for us in the comments, clarify your question.

Comment: Your `print` there demonstrates that the `datetime.datetime.combine(...)` call is working as expected. If you're still having problems you have some different error that there isn't enough information here to debug.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper found the issue, it was with negative hours for `timedelta(hours = -9)` which I need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed and discovered the issue was in `tz`:

```
(datetime.combine(date(1,1,1), datetime.time(4, 35)) + timedelta(hours = tz)).time()
```

When timedelta(hours = tz) with tz = -9 (for example) it became:

```
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=54000)
```

But if you will change the date(1,1,1) to be date(2,1,1) it will work perfectly for my needs.
I can move backward and forward with 27 hours timezone difference without any issue because the `-1` day is covered within `date(2,1,1)`

It will work with the days part too:

```
import datetime

(datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,2), datetime.time(4, 35)) + datetime.timedelta(hours = 27)).time()
```